# title does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I know there is question about this but there is not solution that helps me. So, i have table 'About' in database and model About.php. I want retrieve only one column from db such as title, and use this codes:

```
 $abouts = About::orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
 return view('about')->with('abouts', $abouts);
```

and in view:

```
{{$abouts->title}}
```

and how solve this problem. i don't want to use foreach loop. is it possible? how?

Comment: $abouts = About::select('title')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();. use first() method to retrive only one row

Comment: As per your statement,  $about is populated with a collection of all table content. If you need only one record and you know record `id` you can simply do `$about = About::find(id);` and then in your template you could output just `{{ $about->title }}` without any loop.

Comment: If you never GET the data, then you will always have a Builder...

Answer (score 0):

try **Pluck()**

The pluck method retrieves all of the values for a given key:

```
$collection = collect([
['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'Desk'],
['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'Chair'],
]);

$plucked = $collection->pluck('name');

$plucked->all();

// ['Desk', 'Chair']
```

in controller:

```
$titles = About::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->pluck('title')->all();
return view('about')->with('titles');
```

in blade use:

```
{{$titles[0]}}
```

ref: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck